# Why is my question here considered a bug report?

Tags: discussion, questions

I asked https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/183535/drush-cant-decompress-a-tmp-gz-file as help request and I've no idea if I myself did something wrong (say, installed something wrong) so it would be caused. As I commented in the question, I've opened a similar issue at Git, and it was closed; thus, I came to conclude it may not be a bug.

Answer (score 3):

I closed it per my comment:

> It's an error message you're getting on a stock installation of Drupal, after you've followed all instructions to install and use Drush? That's got to be a bug, or at the very least a feature request for a more descriptive error message. We can't guess from here why Drush can't decompress that file. Maybe you don't have gzip installed? Couldn't say without access to the machine

Perhaps a more appropriate reason would be "Too Broad", I don't know.

Just addressing this:

> I've no idea if I myself did something wrong (say, installed something wrong)

Neither do we - you haven't detailed what steps you *took* for the installation; asking people to guess at all the things you might not have done correctly isn't a good use of Q+A.

Comment: I usually detail, but I though that if I got that far as I did detail generally in the answer, that would be enough and I would be asked if I did anything that I might didn't do....